# XPages sync with SQL Server

Tags: sql, xpages

I am working on a project left from a former colleague.  The XPages application syncs the Notes data with an MS SQL Server database.  Trouble is I cannot seem to find where the Xpages Domino application truely references the MS SQL Server database.  It is a one way data transfer so it is not the case of the MS SQL server database referncing the XPages Notes data.  Can someone tell me where I would find this please?

The MS SQL Server is named ourservername\p40010 and in this server is the relevant database.  There is a Java class in the application named DBUtil.java and has the following statements;

```
public DBUtil() {
     this.connectionName="mssql1";
   }
      public String getConnectionName() {
           return connectionName;
         }

      public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
           if(connection==null) {
               connection = JdbcUtil.getConnection(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance  
                  (),connectionName);
           }
           return connection;
      }
```

Also, in one of the Java classes built for the reports is a statement;

```
  data.setConnectionName("java:comp/env/jdbc/mssql1");
```

However, somewhere "mssql1" must tie in with "ourservername\p40010" but I cannot find where.  Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Thanks in advance

Regards

AJF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be defined as a `mssql1.jdbc` file in `WebContent\WEB-INF\jdbc` folder (visible in Navigator)

Comment: Doh!! Probably the only place I didn't look.  Thank you so much Lauri